# Jekyll: Liquid filter "cgi_escape" returns error for some variables

Tags: jekyll, shopify, liquid

The short version: have you managed to use something like `{{ page.title | cgi_escape }}` in an `{% include %}`-ed partial?

Details follow:

I have a partial that I use like so:

```
{% include mainContainer.html %}
```

Works fine. Then, in that partial, try to display some liquid variables:

`{{ page.title }}` displays the title.

`{{ page.content }}` Displays the content.

`{{ page.content | cgi_escape }}` displays the content, but escaped.

`{{ page.title | cgi_escape }}` doesn't work at all. Creates the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass
```

Aside from `{{ page.content }}` I get the error for any of the `{{ page }}` variables (category, title, etc) but all of them will display fine *without* the filter. Also, `{{ page.title | cgi_escape }}` works okay in the...uhhh...'content' part of the layout (I'm not sure what to call it--the `{{ content }}` section). I only seem to get the error with `{% include %}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll Error "Liquid Exception: undefined method \`encoding' for nil:NilClass in \_layouts/post.html"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571150/jekyll-error-liquid-exception-undefined-method-encoding-for-nilnilclass-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. The build was failing because a few of the pages using `{% include mainContainer.html %}` didn't have any [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) and thus no `page.title` (or whatever). Apparently, Liquid is willing to let `{{ page.title }}` pass if the variable isn't set, but not `{{ page.title | cgi_encode }}`